# Extracting matched word from string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to extract matched word from string. For example

```
Str = "This is Nihar Kulkarni as Indian"
```

Here using LIKE we will fetch all records those contain "%India%", but here I would like extract whole word which matched. Suppose from these string India matched so I want "Indian" as output.

Thanks

Comment: You have not mentioned what efforts _you_ have put in towards this. Have you tried going through the sql docs?

Comment: Yes. it works  in R. But I would like to do this in sql.

Comment: What I understood leads me to a query like `Select 'Indian' as COL1 From MY_TABLE Where COL1 Like '%Indian%'`. But, it is total nonsense, a waste of computing power. Anyways.

Comment: you could make a scalar function.  you can use CHARINDEX to find where the string starts, then you can read backwards and forwards in the string using a loop and SUBSTRING to interrogate single characters, you'd want to look for either a space or the start/end of the string.  Of course there could be a string like.  'Fred was born in India but does not have Indian nationality' where there are two answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
DECLARE @Word varchar(10) = 'India'

SELECT SUBSTRING(V.S,CIw.I, ISNULL(NULLIF(CIs.I,0),LEN(V.S)+1) - CIw.I)
FROM (VALUES('This is Nihar Kulkarni as Indian')) V(S)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(@Word,V.S))) CIw(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(' ',V.S,CIw.I))) CIs(I);
```

This gets the position of the word, and then the next space. If there is no space afterwards, the length of the full value (+1) is used. Note that if you have grammar in your value, for example `'This is Nihar Kulkarni, who is Indian.'` or `'He is Indian, but lives in Europe'` then the value `'Indian.'` or `'Indian,'` would be returned respectively.

Comment: That sentance makes no sense I'm afraid, @Niks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for any word that you like :

```
DECLARE @MatchedWord VARCHAR(50) = 'Indian'
DECLARE @Str  VARCHAR(50) = 'This is Nihar Kulkarni as Indian'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Str,CHARINDEX(@MatchedWord,@Str),LEN(@MatchedWord))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with query below:

```
select * from table_name where Str LIKE 'India%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query. Here first I have inserted all words of given string into a table by separating space. After that using like matching records from that table has been selected.

```
DECLARE @Stringtofindmatching VARCHAR(MAX) = 'This is Nihar Kulkarni as Indian'
DECLARE @table TABLE ( matchingword VARCHAR(50) )
DECLARE @x INT = 0
DECLARE @firstspace INT = 0
DECLARE @nextspace INT = 0

SET @x = LEN(@Stringtofindmatching) - LEN(REPLACE(@Stringtofindmatching, ' ', '')) + 1 -- number of ids in id_list

WHILE @x > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @nextspace = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', @Stringtofindmatching, @firstspace + 1) = 0
                              THEN LEN(@Stringtofindmatching) + 1
                              ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', @Stringtofindmatching, @firstspace + 1)
                         END
        INSERT  INTO @table
        VALUES  ( SUBSTRING(@Stringtofindmatching, @firstspace + 1, (@nextspace - @firstspace) - 1) )
        SET @firstspace = CHARINDEX(' ', @Stringtofindmatching, @firstspace + 1)
        SET @x = @x - 1
    END

SELECT  *
FROM @table where matchingword like '%India%'
```

You can find the live demo [Here](https://rextester.com/BLQ77404).